# How to skip the primary key when inserting ContentValues in SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a little Problem with an insert-Statement in my Android-App.

Here is the code:

```
public void addNote(Note noteItem, int modulNummer){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_NOTE, noteItem.getNote());
        cv.put(COLUMN_NOTEBESCHREIBUNG, noteItem.getBeschreibung());
        cv.put(COLUMN_MODULID_FK, modulNummer);
        db.insert(NOTETABLE, null, cv);
    }
```

Now my problem. The first column in my table is an auto increment pk. And so i want to skip the first column and i want to begin the insert in the second column. How can i skip this first column?

**Update**

I've already deleted the .put for the first column. "COLUMN_NOTE" is my second column. 
My table-structure looks like this:

```
id INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT
note double
beschreibung TEXT
modul_id INTEGER
```

**UPDATE 2**
I don't know why, but now it works. Thx for your help guys.

Comment: which field is the primary key??

Comment: Did you try to insert without first coloumn? If so please let us know what problem you are facing.

Comment: Post your table structure.

Comment: How can i insert without first column?

Comment: I asume `COLUMN_NOTE` is your first coloumn, just remove `cv.put(COLUMN_NOTE, noteItem.getNote());` this line and try to insert.

Comment: The ai-primary key is on the first column. So i want to skip the first. But i cant find a method for that. And a "INSERT ..." statement isn't as nice as this method. :D

Comment: @Gunaseelan No, i've already deleted the one for the first column. And it doesn't work.

Comment: Updated my post with more infos about the structure of my table

Comment: Let us know what problem you are facing. Can you post your logcat error. Because there not neccesary to add `auto-increment` coloumn.

Comment: Check that your column has the AUTOINCREMENT value, if it is there, you should be able to insert removing the PK field. Note that if you had put that value recently you should increase your DB version so the changes can be noticed.

Comment: Now it works. I don't know why. I only restarted the Application and now it works like a charm. :D Thx for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a table like the following one:

```
private final String TAB_GROUP_ADD = "CREATE TABLE groups (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT NOT NULL, description TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

And you use the following insert command:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(K_TITLE, title);
values.put(K_DESCRIPTION, description);
db.insert(TAB_GROUP, null, values);
```

Everything should go fine. The primary key field "id" will no be filled in by Java and the SQLite Database will do it for you.